# Exception in cassandra log

Tags: cassandra, hector, cassandra-cli

I am seeing below exception in my cassandra logs(/var/log/cassandra/system.log)

```
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-02-13 13:13:57,641 GCInspector.java (line 119) GC for ParNew: 273 ms for 1 collections, 2319121816 used; max is 445
6448000
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-02-13 13:14:02,695 GCInspector.java (line 119) GC for ParNew: 214 ms for 1 collections, 2315368976 used; max is 445
6448000
 INFO [OptionalTasks:1] 2014-02-13 13:14:08,093 MeteredFlusher.java (line 64) flushing high-traffic column family CFS(Keyspace='comsdb', ColumnFa
mily='product_update') (estimated 213624220 bytes)
 INFO [OptionalTasks:1] 2014-02-13 13:14:08,093 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 626) Enqueuing flush of Memtable-product_update@1067619242(31239028/
213625108 serialized/live bytes, 222393 ops)
 INFO [FlushWriter:94] 2014-02-13 13:14:08,127 Memtable.java (line 400) Writing Memtable-product_update@1067619242(31239028/213625108 serialized/
live bytes, 222393 ops)
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-02-13 13:14:08,696 GCInspector.java (line 119) GC for ParNew: 214 ms for 1 collections, 2480175160 used; max is 445
6448000
 INFO [FlushWriter:94] 2014-02-13 13:14:10,836 Memtable.java (line 438) Completed flushing /cassandra1/data/comsdb/product_update/comsdb-product_
update-ic-416-Data.db (15707248 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1391568233618, position=13712751)
ERROR [Thrift:13] 2014-02-13 13:15:45,694 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 213) Thrift error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.TException: Negative length: -2147418111
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.checkReadLength(TBinaryProtocol.java:388)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readBinary(TBinaryProtocol.java:363)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_args.read(Cassandra.java:20304)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:21)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:199)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
ERROR [Thrift:103] 2014-02-13 13:21:25,719 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 213) Thrift error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.TException: Negative length: -2147418111
```

Below is my cassandra version and hector client version, which is being used currently

- Cassandra-version: 1.2.11
- Hector-client: 1.0-2

Any lead would be appreciated though we are planning to move cassandra 2.0 version with java-driver but it may take some time meanwhile need to find the root cause and resolve this issue.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is this error causing you problems, aka, why not ignore it?

Comment: problem is, when i am inserting data through hector client i am not getting any exception but when i am trying to get the data through cqlsh and cassandra-cli, i am not getting any data. looks like data is not being persisted in database.